# How to prevent multi triggers in bootstrap modal?

Tags: triggers, modal-dialog

I have a confirm modal shown after a button clicked and in this modal has two buttons, "Cancel" and "Add". The "Add" will expend data into its own item list and it works fine. But if I click "Cancel" and then go back to show this modal again, if then I click "Add", my item list will be expended times depends on how many time I click "Cancel" before. I try .data("bs.modal", null) or .off('click') at .on("hidden.bs.modal"). None of them can fix my problem.

The sample link [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/chennet/L3ddq/730/)

```
<div class="major">
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="additem" value="Add"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> add</button>
    <ul id="itemlist" data="0">
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="major">
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="additem" value="Add"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> add</button>
    <ul id="itemlist" data="100">
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure?
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the script,

```
$('button[name="additem"]').on('click', function(e){
    var $major=$(this).closest('.major');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
    .one('click', '#add', function (e) {
        var num = parseInt($major.children("#itemlist").attr("data")) + 1;
        $major.children("#itemlist").append("<li>new item" + num + "</li>");
        $major.children("#itemlist").attr("data", num);
    });
});

$("#confirm").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(this).data("bs.modal", null);
    $("#add").off("click");
});
```

Comment: can u create fiddle or plunk for the issue ?

Comment: Yes, I did. at above of the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following were the problems :

**Function for "Add Items"**
All the code was inside function for Add Items, So whenever add button was getting called for displaying modal box, modal box's ADD button's code was also executing..

**Jquery .one()**
It will execute only one time, so I have replaced it with on which will be executed on every click to "Add button of Modal"

I have taken code out from the function and replaced one with on, now it works fine !!!

Updated fiddle can be found at : http://jsfiddle.net/L3ddq/732/

```
var $major ;
$('button[name="additem"]').on('click', function(e){
    $major=$(this).closest('.major');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
});

$('#confirm').on('click', '#add', function (e) {
  var num = parseInt($major.children("#itemlist").attr("data")) + 1;
  $major.children("#itemlist").append("<li>new item" + num + "</li>");
  $major.children("#itemlist").attr("data", num);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Does this mean .one() will execute "#add" once even  no one click it?

Comment: No, .one will execute '#add' on the first click only, after that on subsequent click it will not execute #add